# Abrir modal bootstrap e pedir confirmação da senha, caso a senha estiver certa, chamar outro modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, bootstrap-4, modal

Estou pedindo a confirmação de uma senha para o usuário, caso a senha esteja certa, chamar outro modal com outras opções, caso errada, exibir que a senha está errada.

> Creio que não estou sabendo utilizar o jQuery.

1. A variável `$senha` está vindo do banco de dados.
2. Estou utilizando bootstrap versão 4

**Modal confirmar senha:**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm_senha" >
    Quero editar
</button>

<!-- Modal confirmar senha -->
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm_senha" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Confirme a sua senha antes de começar</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" action="">

        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Senha:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha">
          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Confirmar senha:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha_2" maxlength="50">
          </div>
        </div> 

        <hr> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <button type="submit" name="confirmar_senha" class="btn btn-primary">Continuar</button>
      
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['confirmar_senha'])){
        $senha_confirm = $_POST['senha'];
        $senha_confirm_2 = $_POST['senha_2'];

        if ($senha_confirm == $senha && $senha_confirm_2 == $senha) { ?>
                <script>
                  $('#confirm_senha').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { // Fecha essa modal (confirmar senha)
                  $("#edit_user").modal('show');})                   // Abre modal (editar dados)
                </script> 
                
        <?php }else{ echo "As senhas não concidem"; }  } // End IF ?>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ./Modal confirmar senha -->
```

**Outro modal:**

```
 <!-- Modal edit dados usuário -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="edit_user" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar dados do usuário</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
           ...
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <!-- ./Modal edit user -->
```

> Creio que a lógica esteja certa, agradeço a qualquer tipo de ajuda.

O *problema* é que não está abrindo o modal caso a senha esteja certa.

O **console** está apontando erro nessa linha:  `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { // Fecha essa modal (confirmar senha)`

Se eu troco essa linha do `IF` por um `echo "As senhas estão certas";` é exibido normalmente.

***EDIT:*** Eu não consigo abrir o outro `modal` através de um botão dentro de um `<form>`, apenas fora. Tentei colocar o `IF` fora do `<form>` mas também nada (ele abre por botão, mas não pelo jQuery), não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: `($senha_confirm = $senha && $senha_confirm_2 = $senha)` o símbolo de comparação é `==` e não `=`

Comment: Aonde você define a variável `$senha`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de um tempo pesquisando, **consegui resolver** dessa forma:

```
if($senha_confirm == $senha && $senha_confirm_2 == $senha) { 
    echo"  
       <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#confirm_senha').modal('hide'); 
          $('#edit_user').modal('show');})   
       </script>";
             
}else{ 
     echo"
       <script>
          alert('Você digitou a senha errada! Estamos reiniciando a página.');
          setTimeout(function() {window.location.href = 'minha_conta.php'; }, 1000);
       </script>";
}
```